# Rails: Using application helper in index.atom.builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I use an application helper in an index.atom.builder view file?

Trying to use it throws an "undefined method 'xmlschema'" for "test123":String

EDIT: This is the code that's causing the issue.

```
# index.atom.builder
atom_feed do |feed|
  # this application helper method1 returns a string
  feed.updated method1(Time.now)  
end
```

Comment: That doesn't sound like missing application helper functionality. That sounds like you are calling a method on a string that isn't present. You might be expecting it to be a Date or Time but either way posting the code that is causing the problem will help people diagnose.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. The helper method was returning a string and the feed.updated was expected a Time object.

Comment: I wonder how do I use a string for feed.updated?

Comment: Not sure what method1 is doing but if you just need `Time.now` for updated then you can just call `feed.updated`.

Comment: method1 was just converting the time to a different time zone and formatting the time with strftime. However, I found out that the atom feed page has the time automatically converted for me and that the time format was unnecessary. It's likely a standard thing.